# How to fix Eclipse Cdt breakpoint issue?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

My setup:

- Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2)
- Kubuntu 16.04.2, 64 Bit

Started my eclipse today with a debug session on a makefile project → `Debug As → Local C/C++ Application` (as I'd done hundreds times in the past).
As expected, the debugger stops at main(), the debugger console view shows:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffde68) at src/Main.cxx:169
169 {
```

I'm also able to step and watch variables et cetera and also `Ctrl+R` (Run to Line) works.

But for unknown reason, I'm unable to set a breakpoint using eclipse.

- Tried double click at the left margin of the text editor just do nothing.
- Right click (context menu) & `Toggle Breakpoint` shows a message "The chosen operation is not enabled" and the regarding menu entry became disabled (grayed) afterwards.

[image]

However, I'm still able to set breakpoints using gdb command line (using the eclipse debugger console view).

Note, that setting breakpoints have been worked until some days ago, but I don't know what might have been changed in my setup.

Any suggestion what might be wrong in my configuration and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out, that the issue comes up after having installed `Html Editor (Wtp)` via Eclipse Maketplace.

After deinstallation of `Eclipse Web Developer Tools`, the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. Check in **Breakpoints** view even those breakpoints set in gdb will also automatically shown here in this view.
2. Check which editor are you using(Is it C/C++ editor)?
3. Try short cut key (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) for toggle breakpoints. By default short cut keys were not assigned to all breakpoint related commands. So check in preferences.

[image]

Comment: Thx; all that checked, but not solved the issue. Even tried with a new workspace without success. Now completely reinstalled eclipse (and all plugins).